# CRONTAB like component for Angular 6

Tags: angular, job-scheduler

I need a time based scheduler component for Angular, consider it like windows task scheduler or cron.
Users will use that part to schedule tasks for monthly, weekly or daily basis.

Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW, I tried this but did not work: http://angular-cron-jobs.github.io/angular-cron-jobs/#/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used ngx-cron-editor https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cron-editor and it worked well.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your own answer (you may have to wait until the system will allow this). Doing so will help others who read this  question in future

Comment: @Arthur Cam, Could you please share the code snippet of how did you achieve this. I'm new to node and angular, and I want to implement cron jobs